# Animated load of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm a total newbie in ios, so judge my question by that.

I have a code to use. In the code i have a vertical tabbar controller inherited from FSVerticalTabBarController. We use this tabbar controller to switch between viewcontrollers.

What i want is to have the viewcontrollers come up with an animation. Any kind of default animation is fine. How can i do that? here's the code, and thank you for your help:

```
    @implementation AIVerticalTabBarController

@synthesize appDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setDelegate:self];

    [[self tabBar] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home", @"Export", @"Settings", @"Titles", @"Slides", @"Text doc", nil];
    NSArray *viewClasses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AIViewController", @"AIViewController", @"AIViewController", @"AITitlesViewController", @"AISlidesViewController", @"AIViewController", nil];

    NSMutableArray *controllersToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [titles count]; i++) {
        AIViewController *viewC = [[NSClassFromString([viewClasses objectAtIndex:i]) alloc] init];
        [viewC setAppDelegate:appDelegate];
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[titles objectAtIndex:i] image:nil tag:i];



        [viewC setTabBarItem:tbi];



        [controllersToAdd addObject:viewC];
    }

    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:controllersToAdd] animated:YES];




}
@end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by adding this method to your appDelegate 
dont forget to import the QuartzCore lib 

`-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{`

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //choose your animation
[viewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:viewController.view];

return YES;
```

}