# Animate through tabs in a custom UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, uitabbar

i have a custom tab bar in my application. how do i animate when navigation through different tabs? here is my code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtab.png"];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:image];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor =[UIColor brownColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
```

apple docs say that we should pot the following code but it does not work

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: See: [iPhone: How to switch tabs with an animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation)

Comment: @mopsled that method does not apply to this instance. it will not work here. i jut need to know how to add yes to the bool type above.