# How to add transition for switching between tabbar viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, transition

I added `UITabBarViewController` to my app and added five `ViewControllers`. Each `VC` to one of the `TabBarItems`. And all of this is working good. But for the third `view` is made for user to input some data, so I want it to be presented as temporary `VC`. The usual transition for temporary `VC` is crossdisolve. This brings the `VC` up from the bottom.

So my question is **how can I make this animation for transition between TabBarItems**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How to switch tabs with an animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function which takes in the index of the destination view. I would add this function as part of the parent view controller to be called by the sub-view controllers. That's up to you.

```
-(void) animateTabBarTransition:(NSInteger) destinationTabIdx{
   UIView * fromView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
   UIView * toView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:destinationTabIdx] view];

  [UIView transitionFromView:fromView toView:toView duration:0.8
    options:(destinationTabIdx > self.tabBarController.selectedIndex ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight)
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = destinationTabIdx;
                }
}];
```

}