# Can I make a UITabBarController switch tabs programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController template based app where the first tab is a UITableViewController with custom buttons in the cells.  I need one button in one cell to call a specific tab in the parent UITabBarController.  Im using this code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
case 5:
            NSLog(@"Search");
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            // Get UITabBar instance and send it message
            UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController*)[self parentViewController];
            [tabBar setSelectedIndex:1];

            break;
```

When I tap on this row the app crashes without any log in the console.  Im calling this in that UITableViewController which is the first tab in the UITabBarController.

PS I also want to avoid the blue selection on this cell that occurs when the user taps.  So I added this code:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
            return nil;
            break;
    }
}
```

But it still selects blue when I tap on it.  Could they be related issues?

Comment: you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation)?

Comment: you can avoid the blue selection by setting the selection style `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` for your cells. What does `case 5`refer to in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *) UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;
    [tabController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

the first message will deselect the row, avoiding the blue selection.

As your app is tab-based, the root controller of the key window is always an instance of `UITabBarController`.