# UITabBar disables when simulraneously click 2 buttons

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, transition, uitabbar

I currently have the following "controller tree":

> UITabBarController
>   ┣━ UIViewController (**A**)
>   ┃  ┗ MKMapView
>   ┣━ UINavigationController
>   ┃  ┣━ UITableViewController (**X**)
>   ┃  ┗━ UITableViewController (**B**)
>   ┣━ UIViewController (not interesting)
>   ┗━ UIViewController (not interesting)

In second view (B) i have button connected to the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)mapButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
        UIView *startView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
        UIView *endView = ((UIViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:ELMapViewControllerIndex]).view;
        ElMainMapViewController *carparkVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:ELMapViewControllerIndex];
        [UIView transitionFromView:startView toView:endView duration:ELAnimationDuration
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        }];
    }
```

The code has been taken from: 
[iPhone: How to switch tabs with an animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation)

Everything works perfeclty fine - When button i click on the button my second tab view slighty changes to first and everything works as I want to.

Unfortunately my QA clicked simultaneously back button and button connected to the function above. That sometimes cause locking `UITabBar`. I'm able to move `MKMapView` and any subview but `UITabBar` behave like with disabled user interaction.

If this "combo" doesn't lock `UITabBar` it sometimes cause "<" sign near back button in **B** ViewController is much thinner then it should be.

I really don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I checked viewWillAppear and other function but none of have a deal with `UITabBar` (I don't keep reference in any other function to `UITabBar`).

**EDIT**

I removed changing selected index in tabBar and this issue still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the controls before starting the animation re-enable them in the completion block.

For each item use something like:

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setEnabled:NO];
```

and then `setEnabled:YES` on animation completion.