# Change tabbarController's tab programmatically with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, core-animation

I want to change tab through code with animation. Exact scenario is that there are 2 tabs with below hierarchy.

```
First tab
  - Navigation controller
    - Login controller
    - Some other controller
Second tab
  - Navigation controller
    - Screen with Logout button
```

Now, if user presses logout, I need to display login screen. For that I need to switch tab to `FirstTab` and then popToRootViewController.

So what I am doing is on logout button press I send `NSNotification` to `LoginController` which in turn executes below method.

```
- (void)logoutButtonPressed
{
    // Go to root controller in navigation controller of first tab.
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Change tab to "First tab". This happens sharply without animation.
    // I want to animate this change.
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I tried below method to animate. But this animates only when tab is changed by user but not when changed through code.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSArray *tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    UIView * fromView = tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = viewController.view;
    if (fromView == toView)
        return false;
    NSUInteger fromIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    NSUInteger toIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:0.3
                       options: toIndex > fromIndex ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (finished) {
                            tabBarController.selectedIndex = toIndex;
                        }
                    }];

    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation

Comment: try my implementation and let me know

Comment: Have you tried to set a delay after call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, maybe a 1 or 2 seconds delay?. I've made it with my app and worked well. I mean, first select the tab and then call the method with a delay. It's an option.

Comment: @ThXou Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code I used to animate screens with slide in-out effect. Found on [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180104/1798394).

```
- (void)logoutButtonPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [self animateTransitionBetweenControllers];
}

// Animates view transition that happens from screen with logout button to login screen
- (void)animateTransitionBetweenControllers
{
    // Get the views to animate.
    UIView * fromView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view];

    // Get the size of the view.
    CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

    // Add the view that we want to display to superview of currently visible view.
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

    // Position it off screen. We will animate it left to right slide.
    toView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.bounds.size.width, viewSize.origin.y, toView.bounds.size.width, viewSize.size.height);

    // Animate transition
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
        // Animate the views with slide.
        fromView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, viewSize.origin.y, toView.bounds.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
        toView.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, toView.bounds.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished)
        {
            // Remove the old view.
            [fromView removeFromSuperview];
            self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)logoutButtonPressed
{
    // Go to root controller in navigation controller of first tab.
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    NSArray *tabViewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;


    UIView * fromView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;


    UIView * toView = self.view;

    NSUInteger fromIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:self.tabBarController.selectedViewController];


    NSUInteger toIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:self];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:0.3
                       options: toIndex > fromIndex ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

                    }];


}
```

Comment: This works. But I want to animate with default animation, not with flip.

Comment: what kind of animation do u want?

Comment: iOS default animation. i.e. transition from right to left. in other words, animation that happens on popping a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sorry Geek, I was disconnected on weekend.

The solution that I took in my app was make a method which call to the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` and then send a `performSelector:` message to `self` passing that created method as a selector:

```
- (void)delayPopAnimation {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// in logoutButtonPressed make some like this
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[self performSelector:@selector(delayPopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
```

Maybe it is not the best and well performed solution, but it's an option because do the work. It will select the tab and after a 1.5 second delay, the animation will take place. Hope it helps.