# Segue from one ViewController to another ViewController inside a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uitabbar

In the interface builder I have a `UITabBarController` and it is set as the initial view controller. From the tab bar controller, I have linked three independent ViewControllers; two `UIViewController`'s and one `UITableViewController`. I have embedded all three of these views inside `UINavigationController`'s as each of these views will eventually segue to a new view.

[Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOIV4.png)

Problem:

I now want to link one of the `UIViewController`'s to the `UITableViewController` using a button to segue to the table view. This way I can pass information, i.e. `func prepareForSegue()`, to the table view. I want to maintain the tab bar controller at the bottom, however I do not want to have the ability to go back to the previous `UIViewController` from the current `UITableViewController` via a `UIBarButtonItem` at the the top of the view; That is what the tab bar at the bottom is for.

However every time I segue "Show" the table view (it is actually a segue to the table views navigation controller), the navigation bars at the top and the bottom of the table view disappear. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

I have also tried segue "Show" directly to the table view, in which case the tab bar is visible, but then it displays a "back" button at the top of the view to segue back to the sending `UIViewController`. I am hesitant about accepting a solution that would just hide the back button, because I feel I will run into problems down the road when I want to navigate to a detail view from the table view itself, since I would be bypassing the `UITableViewController`'s `UINavigationController`.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to solve this problem for hours and I'm about to put my head through my computer screen. Also I thought about just using `tabBarController?.selectedIndex` on the button click to shift to the table view, and then passing the information using `NSUserDefaults`, but this is out of the question since I would be passing a custom object, and would have to encode and decode every custom field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you use a segue to get to it, as you say, you will still be using the `UIViewController`'s `UINavigationController` which seems a bit messy. So I actually think `selectedIndex` is probably the best way to go as once you change to the `UITableViewController` you'll be in the correct navigation stack.

Instead of using `NSUserDefaults`, why not just reference the `UITableView` itself from the `UIViewController`, set the values you want, and then swap to it using `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`.

So for your scenario above it, assuming the `UITableViewContollrer` is the third view in the `UITabBarController`, you would do something like the following:

1. Pass whatever you want into the `UITabBarController` by setting some pre-defined `var` in it. For example, if there was a `String` called `saveMe` in the `UITableViewController`, then do the following in the `UIViewController`:

   ```
   let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController
   let tableViewController = navController.viewControllers.first as! JarListTableViewController
   tableViewController.saveMe = "Saved string here"
   ```
2. Swap to the `UITableViewController` using:

   ```
   self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
   ```

The only issue with this is using `selectedIndex` won't perform a transition animation but not sure if you need this. [This link could help if you do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425337/change-tabbarcontrollers-tab-programmatically-with-animation)

Comment: Thanks this worked... kinda. I had to change one thing. You can't cast a `UINavigationController` `as!` a `JarListTableViewController`. Instead of `let tableViewController = navController as! JarListTableViewController` you have to say `let tableViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! JarListTableViewController`. That's all. If you update your answer i'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. I forgot to add that part in. I actually do it a slightly different way that I've corrected above. Hopefully you didn't waste too much time on my stupid mistake!

Comment: Either way will work, I just prefer using full words rather than the numbers.

Comment: Hmm didn't realize that `.first` was a keyword for arrays... either way, thanks again!