# Transition Delegate for UITabBarController animation

Tags: ios, swift, transition, xcode6, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a custom `UIViewControllerAnimationTransition` class created already, and need to make this animate a `UITabBarController` when it switches tabs.

The `tabBarController` does not use the regular tab bar, though. I have a custom implementation that acts like it, and when a button is pressed, it calls this code:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = index
```

Currently I have the `tabBarController` (subclass) as the delegate for its own `transitionDelegate`. The delegate method `animationControllerForPresentedController` is never actually called, though.

Is it fine for the tab bar controller to be its own delegate? If so, why is the transition code never actually called?

Comment: there's a really good solution here that explains it

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5180104/2855836

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`animationControllerForPresentedController` is the wrong approach for the tab bar controller.

In the UITabBarController subclass, adopt the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and set it as its own `delegate`. Then, use `tabBarController: animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController: toViewController:` to return the custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` object.

To get a better visualization, look at [VCTransitionsLibrary](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary) in the TabBarDemo folder.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate` instead of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`?

Comment: No, I mean, shouldn't it be `delegate`, instead of `transitionDelegate`! My bad.

Comment: @AndréFratelli don't think so. The delegate and the transition delegate do different things. The delegate handles events like when a button is pressed, while the transition delegate handles animations.

Comment: Yes, but it's the delegate and not the transition delegate that implements `tabBarController:animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:toViewController:`

Comment: @AndréFratelli OK I see what you mean. I'm surprised nobody else caught that before :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use these delegate methods like this?

```
@interface BTSlideInteractor : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>

- (IBAction)showModalButtonWasTouched:(id)sender
{
    BTSlideInteractor *interactor = [[BTSlideInteractor alloc] init];
    interactor.presenting = YES;

    BTModalViewController *modalController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModalViewController"];
    modalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    modalController.transitioningDelegate = interactor;
    [self presentViewController:modalController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Use this link for Reference: https://github.com/brightec/CustomViewControllerTransition/blob/master/test/BTViewController.m

If you didnt find the solution kindly add your codes.

Comment: Are you saying that the trabsition delegate should be set for the *view controllers* not the tab bar?