# How to reproduce the "sibling to sibling" animation between viewControllers

Tags: ios

I am struggling to reproduce the ["sibling to sibling navigational transition"](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#navigational-transitions-sibling-to-sibling) between viewControllers.

I have a UITabBar with 3 items. I can make the VC switch animated with something like

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight // or FromLeft depending on context 
[viewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

**But in this case the fromViewController disappears instantly**, and the app background is shown.

I could take a screenshot of the fromViewController and insert it somewhere on the toViewController but I would also have to animate it, I suspect it would ends messy.

What you be the simpliest way to reproduce this effect (preferably without using a large horizontal scrollview) ?

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24938950/881989

Comment: Seems like the perfect job for a `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: @DrBeardface do you have an example of how to setup this with a UITabar ? Thanks.

Comment: @SergeyKuryanov does that deal with the previous controller animation ?

Comment: On that answer you can see explanation for to deal with custom transitions between you tab bar view controllers.