# UIViewController - why doesn't following animate in the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I created a simple tab bar app with 2 view controllers - `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. I added the following to the First, why doesn't this animate?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration: 2.0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                      animations:^(void){
                          [super viewWillAppear:YES ];
                      } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: Don't ever call `viewWillAppear:` or any of the lifecycle methods yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot animate because (1) `viewWillAppear` is too soon — the view isn't even in the interface yet, so what's to animate? and (2) it's not up to you to animate this view into place — if you wanted to do that, you'd have to write a custom transition animation, and that's not how to do it.

Comment: It's utterly unclear from your code what you're hoping to do, and your question doesn't explain your intentions. But whatever they are, that code is wrong in every sense.

Comment: Why doesn't this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation

Comment: Is that what you are trying to do? Change tabs in a tab bar controller with animation?

Comment: Yes.. when you click on tab. The tab animates into view. That's it

Comment: It's all in my book! Here's the example I develop there: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p292customAnimation1/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.swift As I said, you have to write a custom transition animation. This shows you how.

Comment: thanks.. how does this transfer to iOS - this is swift? correct

Comment: I've answered the question. I've given you working code in a project that you can download and run. I've written you a book that explains that code to you! I really think my job here is done.

Comment: Yes.. thanks.. it's in swift and runs great. Looking to do it Xcode

Comment: You are doing it in Xcode already. Do you mean you need the same thing in Objective-C? https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p292customAnimation1/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m