# UITabBarController Tab Modal Presentation -Swift2 OS

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a tabBarController with 2 tabs: tab1 and tab2. I have a button named pressButton in tab1. When pressed it automatically switches to tab2. How do I present tab2 modally upon switching tabs?

The thing is I want to keep both tabs visible at the bottom after the modal presentation. The docs say that a modal presentation will completely take over the entire screen. I don't want the modal to hide the bottom tabBarController tabs. How would I do this?

```
@IBOutlet func pressButton(sender: UIButton){
   self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: We cant do modally for tabbar. You can take two button and then implement the modal animation on button click

Comment: @ user3774439 Thanks for the help. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

For customization of tab bar use the following link

[Customization of Tabbar using button](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar)

in the button actions, use the modal animation for displaying the tabbar.

Happy Coding...

Comment: thanks I'll try it this weekend and if all good I'll use as the accepted answer. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Soory for taking so long, I just got a chance to read the link you sent. It's a god link but it;s not what I'm looking for. I already have the tabBarController in Storyboard. What I need to do id change how the tab get presented, I want 1 of the tabs to be presented modally. Your example would work but I already have a ton of code using the tabBArController and each tab. it would be a lot of work to redo everything over. There has to be some animation to modally present a tab using the tabBar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161730/iphone-how-to-switch-tabs-with-an-animation   Check this link