# Infobutton not Displaying ModalView

Tags: iphone

When pressing infobutton it is not displaying ModalView

```
  UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(displayModalView:)]; 




- (void)displayModalView 
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.viewController = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];  

[navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

[_window addSubview:navigationController.view];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   

}
```

Anyone can help me please what is the problem in this.

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me out

Comment: Can you please specify some more details to me so I can answer: where do you intend to use the `UIBarButtonItem` on a navigation bar? I see that your problem is here as this created button is not linked to the button that you see on the bar, so you are pressing a button that doesn't have the code you specified inside it.

Comment: This InfoButton is on UIToolbar.

Comment: can you please explain me when you say problem is here as this created button is not linked to the button that you see on the bar, so you are pressing a button that doesn't have the code you specified inside it.

Comment: I am writing an answer, just give me the time to do the typing :)

Answer (score 2):

In your question you didn't specify how you created your objects (the toolBar and the buttons on it), are you creating them from Xcode by dragging and dropping or from pure code, therefore I will try to point out the common issues for both cases.

First, I am assuming that you are using Xcode and dragging the components that you like. In this case you need to create in the .h file an Outlet that will be linked to the button on the bar as follows:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;

- (void) barButtonPress;
```

Notice that I added a function that will handle the bar button press. Now you need to link this Outlet to the bar button item, simply in Xcode in the *Connection Inspector* where it says *New Referencing Outlet* drag to the File's Owner box (the yellow cube).

Now in the `viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
[barButton setTarget:self];
[barButton setAction:@selector(barButtonPress)];
```

This code will link your bar button to the function that you want to be called when you press it. Now for the view that you like to view Modal, I assume that you already `#import` it also in the .h file, lets call it MyViewModal.

Inside the function that will be called when you press the bar button:

```
- (void) barButtonPress
{
    MyViewModal *myViewModal = [[MyViewModal alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewModal" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:myViewModal animated:YES];
}
```

That's all, it will be displayed in Modal View. Keep in mind the allocating the new view is done based on your needs, here I did the simplest case just for illustration.

**UPDATE: If not using Xcode**

If you are not using Xcode then you should have a toolbar already defined say it is named myToolBar. To add buttoms to the tool bar we use the `myToolbar.items` way therefore we need to prepare the buttons with their targets before adding them. Here is a workflow:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(barButtonPress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents]; //same function as above
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton] autorelease];
myTool.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn, nil];
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: i m not using interface builder. creating everything programmtically

Comment: I will update the answer to show the programming way, couple of minutes :)

Comment: i m still struggling with this. Let me see. But thanks a lot for spending your time in helping me out. Appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: UIButton *infoItem =  [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
                          infoItem.frame = CGRectMake(250.0, 8.0, 25.0, 25.0);
                          infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      [infoItem addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                           infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


Now my whole application is crashing saying that UIButton view. Have no idea why my whole application is crashing.

Any ideas Please.

Comment: Well first we need to know what is the error that Xcode is showing when it crashes, this will guide us where to go. A common error is to release an object that already has a count of 0 or try to use a dead object. These are called Zombies and it helps a lot to use a Zombie Profile (from the menu: Product->Profile->Memory->Zombies). The profile shows you the count of each object and if a Zombie is detected it tells you on which object... Please write for us the error that Xcode is showing you when crashing to be more specific in providing ideas.

Comment: UIButton view unrecognized selectoor sent to instance

Comment: An unrecognized selector is a call to a function that is not in that class. A selector means the functions that you call in the class. So this error means you are sending the UIButton instance a function call that does not belong to that class. By the way, the code you provided in the previous comment doesn't have this problem, please review all your code because it should be in some other UIButton.

Comment: now it is working but there is gap between the status bar and the modal view

Comment: First, happy for you that it is working after all. Second, to share the knowledge for everyone, maybe you can tell us how were you able to fix it or what was the error. Third, can you please explain more what do you mean by "there is a gap..."?

Comment: Modalviewcontroller is showing gap after loading. Gap is after staus bar which moved modalviewcontroller down and gap shows me main window. So how i can remove this gap which is showing between status bar and modalviewcontroller.

Comment: UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]; I made these changes to infobutton and now it is working but when modalview displays it shows gap after the staus bar which pushed modalview down.

Comment: Is the gap size approximately equal to the toolbar size?

Comment: yes it is equal to the status bar size which shows battery sign and the carrier sign

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144502/how-come-some-of-my-uiviews-are-shifted-after-navigation) can help you

Comment: By adding the view frame size

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
fixed the gap between status bar and modal view.