# UIImagePickerController when dismissed getting redbar with app name using UITabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the UIImagePickerController to record video and take a picture, edit and save Video to a file. While dismissing the UIImagePickerController the status bar blinks red and disappears and some time my tabbar is moved down.
not able to get why this is occuring where is the issue.

[image] 
 I want to avoid this. I have been noticing this in decreasing frequency from iOS8.1, iOS8, iOS7.1 ,etc

tabbar moving down some time (means randomly).[image]

why rebar is coming when i am recording video and uploading in server or using cancel button in uiimagepickerviewcontreller . .why its not coming in when i am taking image and why  its coming  randomaly not coming every time.

```
    -(void)mediaAction{

/// calling action sheet action 
        }

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //setting for image
    cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.delegate = self;


    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Record a Video"]) {
        mediachecker=@"video";
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Upload from Gallery"]) {
        //NSLog(@"ChooseFromGallery");
        mediachecker=@"video";
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Click a Picture"]) {

        mediachecker=@"photo";
        cameraUI.allowsEditing=YES;
        cameraUI.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];
        //NSLog(@"UseCamera");

    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Photo Library"]) {
        //NSLog(@"UseGallery");
        mediachecker=@"photo";
        cameraUI.allowsEditing=YES;
        cameraUI.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
    }

}  



 - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

                [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            //getting file here; and uploading 
}


- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {


[[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            //dissming here; 

            }
```

i have referred these links
[Redbar Noticed when dismissing UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651355/redbar-noticed-when-dismissing-uiimagepickercontroller)

[IPhone - After dismissing Modal View Controller - gap is left at top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272912/iphone-after-dismissing-modal-view-controller-gap-is-left-at-top-of-page)

but still getting same issue. how to solve this.

Comment: Have you added some edge insets to your tabbar ?

Comment: no ,i have not added

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a UIImagePickerViewController dismissing when taking videos:  not to recursively reference Stack Overflow links, but this solved it for me:

Try:  "you should set "View controller-based status bar appearance" value to YES in the .plist"

[UIImagePickerController messing tabbar frame when dismissing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075126/uiimagepickercontroller-messing-tabbar-frame-when-dismissing)

Not sure why that answer references this, and it wasn't answered here.